# Styling action.submit button doesn't work in Adaptive card

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I've tried adding `style` for a Submit button in the designer as well as in the local setup, but it doesn't seem to work in any of the Adaptive cards' versions.

For some reason, when multiple items are being rendered, the last button has got another background color for which I tried adding a style but it doesn't work.
[image]

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.2",
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Submit",
            "style": "destructive"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Teams Does not support Card action button styling in cards. This is by design. The same is mentioned as a note here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions?tabs=json#adaptive-cards-actions

Comment: Thanks, but could you help me know why the last button in the row (from the screenshot) has blue background color when the card is being opened in the Message extension?

Comment: can you please share the doc or sample code you are using?

Comment: this is what happens with the code provided with multiple Action buttons, but it is only happening in the case of messaging extension

Comment: We tried by placing aboive json in sample https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search. It is rendering as expected. could you please share a sample code and more details of how you are implementing it?